# caching file content in angular 13

Tags: angular, typescript, caching

is there any way to cache file content in angular without using image url
here is how the response body looks :

```
{
  "id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
  "fileName": "string",
  "fileExtention": "string",
  "contentType": "string",
  "fileSize": 0,
  "refId": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
  "content": "string"
}
```

I made lots of searches but in most time they are using url to cache image
thanks in advance ❤

Comment: Your question is not clear, what do you mean by caching in URL? could you explain the core problem in detail, if possible with a working example!]

Comment: i just need to cache the response body @NarenMurali